# jQuery ajax error on PHP response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, error-handling

I build a `webservice` and need to implement proper `error-handling`.

So in PHP, I did:

```
if($error){
    error_log("Empty response for ".$url);
    header('HTTP', true, 500);
    return 'An error occured';
}
```

And in jQuery:

```
$( document ).ajaxError(function(xhr, status) {
    alert(xhr.responseText);
});
```

However,

> **xhr.responseText** is "undefined".

What's wrong?

Comment: Because per documentation [ajaxError](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxerror/) your anonymous function is missing the first parameter, which is `event`, not `xhr`.  Should be `$(document).ajaxError(function(event, xhr, status) {...});`